# How does Appengine/Amazon/Heroku instances work?

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku, amazon-s3, cluster-computing

I know that there are tons of documentation on the subject already, but I was just looking for a simple explanation how does the instances the Appengine or some other provides really work.

I know how it works if the applied software not complicated, but I'm interested in the following case.

Let's say I write a program that listens for incoming connection on port 8888? If I would run that server on my normal server, it would open port 8888 and start listening, but it could theoretically only be able to accept the 65.535 connections (because there are only as much ports available on any system). In practise this number is considerably lower, but let's talk theory. If I wanted to scale that application I would need to add another computer in the local area network and also provide a load balancer that would load the incoming connections evenly on the two machines. But the problem doesn't stop there: what if the incoming clients needed to access each others data, which would mean that I also need to synchronize the database in the background, so both servers holds a copy of all of the data in the database (whatever database this might be). This would probably also require additional configuration of the server and writting an additional piece of code to add to the server program. We've just encountered a myriad of problems, but let's outline them again:

1. Adding another server into the LAN.
2. Configuring both servers to support clustering.
3. Writing additional code in the server process to be aware of the clustering being in place.
4. Load balancing the incoming connections.
5. Replicating of the data in the backend database.

But this isn't the whole story yet. What if I need to implement a two-communication chat server with clustering in mind where two users need to chat in real time. What if the first user is connected to first server and the second user to the second server, how would I send the data from the first to sencond and the other way around, it's very complex problem. This adds another problem to the table:

1. Real-time communication between users connected to different servers.

The problems above are quite complex and they can't be so easily solved. We need countless hours to think about it, and solve it piece by piece. But the solutions like Appengine/Amazon/Heroku say that they will take care about it all. So here are my questions.

1. How do the instances by various provides really work, I'm interested in the following three:

   - Appengine
   - Amazon
   - Heroku
2. How can they scale the server application, so that it supports more than 65k connected users at the same time?
3. How can they encure that even if more instances is running, the data in the backend database is the same no matter which instance pulls the data from the DB?
4. Can the real-time communications between users connected to different instances really work the way they should?
5. If all the software runs on a hardware of some kind, how do they implement the same number of instances to work together that would normally requite like 10 hardware servers to be connected to a cluster.

I guess the explanation of the above problem can really help developers/programmers/administrators to better understand how the instances really work. I guess we can't really decide which product to use if we don't know how it works.

Thank you

Comment: How much of these "tons of documentation" have you tried reading? I bet your questions are quite well covered. The big point of cloud hosting solutions is however that you make these issues someone else's problem.

Comment: and you can't open connections on ports anyway. not yet. The short answer is that you write your application with scaling in mind from the start which means you end up with a very different application to a non-scaling version. THis is a good book to get started in the cloud> http://www.amazon.co.uk/Code-Cloud-Pragmatic-Programmers-Chu-Carroll/dp/1934356638/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1353151153&sr=8-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How do the instances by various provides really work?

   Appengine : work like process base. You don't have a real server. App Engine will try to serve your web service with it cloud architect and calculate how many resource you use such as how many cpu time, db query, web request etc. You don't need to do any thing to scale or expand it.

   Amazon (EC2 Instance) : You create and run the instances then use it like a normal physical server. Scale and architect like physical server. You may need Amazon S3 for storage and Amazon RDS for database.

   Heroku : Heroku instance call dyno. Each dyno serve each job service e.g. web process, background process, scheduler process. For example, if you create 1 web dyno, it like you have 1 apache web server with 1 process running to serve your website. Each request to service need to finish before process next request and queue request time out is 30s. You can create as many dyno as you want. Heroku come with postgresql that you need to pay for cache size.
2. For scalable, I already mention how to scale in previous answer.

   For supporting more than 65k connections. You can create instance as many as you want to serve any connections.
3. The database is store in separate system. From your description, I think your application have individual database on each server. But when you move to PaaS, it like you have a single database in the back-end. Each instance will connect to the same database that make sure you will get the same data no matter where instance user connected to.
4. It depend on how you architect your application. For example if you create a chat application with below process flow :

   - Sender

     1. Sender Client send message to Chat Server
     2. Chat Server store message to DB
   - Reciever

     1. Reciever Client pull update message from Chat Server
     2. Chat Server get update message from DB
     3. Chat Server send update message to receiver

   With above flow, You don't need to worry about which instance each user connected to because each user will always get the same data from the same database (may be delay read/write to database but in the end user will get the same message).
5. You don't need to do that because you have 1 single database. In back-end you can scale database as big and powerful as you want but front-end to application will be the same.